# My new Macbook (Sierra with touch bar) restarts every time I close the lid

Tags: sleep-wake, macos, kernel-panic, touch-bar

Here is the kernel panic:

```
Anonymous UUID:       2553145D-8FD9-2DA2-070C-9095DBCBAEA6

Sun Nov 20 03:50:53 2016

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 4): Unresponsive processor (this CPU did not acknowledge interrupts) TLB state:0x0
RAX: 0x919918be8a0b95ec, RBX: 0x00000593fd1d296f, RCX: 0x0000000058277e3c, RDX: 0x000000000000000d
RSP: 0xffffff82012a3d78, RBP: 0xffffff82012a3db0, RSI: 0x000000000000001e, RDI: 0xffffff8016008e10
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff81f52be058
R12: 0x00000593fd1d3333, R13: 0x00000593fd1d4676, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff8037dde000
RFL: 0x0000000000000a83, RIP: 0xffffff80158a2aa5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f539ef70 : 0xffffff8015a05991 
0xffffff81f539efd0 : 0xffffff80158a5909 
0xffffff82012a3db0 : 0xffffff80158a1ff5 
0xffffff82012a3dd0 : 0xffffff8015ebcc15 
0xffffff82012a3df0 : 0xffffff8015ebf9f5 
0xffffff82012a3e60 : 0xffffff7f966d1a3b 
0xffffff82012a3eb0 : 0xffffff7f966d60ff 
0xffffff82012a3ee0 : 0xffffff8015b8ab62 
0xffffff82012a3fb0 : 0xffffff80158a2af7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7f966c9000->0xffffff7f966f5fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16B2659

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Wed Oct 19 20:31:56 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.4~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 75CA1C4D-7BF4-321B-B544-D8F1B6D60EF8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000015600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015700000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6133164901723
last loaded kext at 5853861817281: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f99ba7000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 4003534972023: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f99b9b000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.radiosilenceapp.nke.PrivateEye  1.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.23
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.1f7
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.kext.AMD9500Controller    1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 103
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1110.4.1a8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.23
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.74
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.0.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.20.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Panic(CPU 6): Unresponsive processor (this CPU did not acknowledge interrupts) TLB state:0x0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff80160bb210, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x000000000002840e
RSP: 0xffffff922c6d3d80, RBP: 0xffffff922c6d3db0, RSI: 0x000000000000001e, RDI: 0xffffff8037e32000
R8:  0x0000000000000004, R9:  0x0000000000000003, R10: 0x0000000000000020, R11: 0x0000000000000034
R12: 0x0000000000000004, R13: 0xffffff82012dd048, R14: 0xffffff8037e099a0, R15: 0x0000000000000028
RFL: 0x0000000000000246, RIP: 0xffffff7f97090946, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f53bdf70 : 0xffffff8015a05991 
0xffffff81f53bdfd0 : 0xffffff80158a5909 
0xffffff922c6d3db0 : 0xffffff7f9716bd4e 
0xffffff922c6d3e30 : 0xffffff7f97306da4 
0xffffff922c6d3ea0 : 0xffffff7f970a44a7 
0xffffff922c6d3ee0 : 0xffffff8015ebe7df 
0xffffff922c6d3f30 : 0xffffff8015ebd041 
0xffffff922c6d3f80 : 0xffffff8015ebc626 
0xffffff922c6d3fb0 : 0xffffff80158a2af7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360(1110.4.1a8)[83E28ECB-4EDE-37A3-8CDB-558E0346453E]@0xffffff7f97081000->0xffffff7f97840fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.corecapture(1.0.4)[A9DCF53D-2E9D-3323-913B-35A40D735F44]@0xffffff7f96f57000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[DFE569DA-088F-3773-95A7-1C98F4E80CEF]@0xffffff7f96f89000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.12.2)[4B50E6E6-0F92-30E2-AFC5-2F67FE8B09D4]@0xffffff7f96f91000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[A55C1363-A09F-3755-9BD3-526A7A2C3B5B]@0xffffff7f96132000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7f966c9000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360(1110.4.1a8)[83E28ECB-4EDE-37A3-8CDB-558E0346453E]@0xffffff7f97081000->0xffffff7f97840fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.corecapture(1.0.4)[A9DCF53D-2E9D-3323-913B-35A40D735F44]@0xffffff7f96f57000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[DFE569DA-088F-3773-95A7-1C98F4E80CEF]@0xffffff7f96f89000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.12.2)[4B50E6E6-0F92-30E2-AFC5-2F67FE8B09D4]@0xffffff7f96f91000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[A55C1363-A09F-3755-9BD3-526A7A2C3B5B]@0xffffff7f96132000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.2)[6326DB88-5330-3F0C-91F6-D478AB5E7503]@0xffffff7f966c9000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80159e629d): "TLB invalidation IPI timeout: " "CPU(s) failed to respond to interrupts, unresponsive CPU bitmap: 0x50, NMIPI acks: orig: 0x0, now: 0x2"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.21.4/osfmk/x86_64/pmap.c:2724
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff922d0ab880 : 0xffffff80158f368c 
0xffffff922d0ab900 : 0xffffff80159e629d 
0xffffff922d0ab9a0 : 0xffffff80159ed01e 
0xffffff922d0abaa0 : 0xffffff80159edfca 
0xffffff922d0abb10 : 0xffffff801597b0b8 
0xffffff922d0abc50 : 0xffffff801597a9bc 
0xffffff922d0abc80 : 0xffffff8015976523 
0xffffff922d0abcb0 : 0xffffff8015d8d8ee 
0xffffff922d0abd50 : 0xffffff8015d8daee 
0xffffff922d0abd90 : 0xffffff8015d90add 
0xffffff922d0abe20 : 0xffffff8015d90ce1 
0xffffff922d0abf50 : 0xffffff8015e27cba 
0xffffff922d0abfb0 : 0xffffff80158a5f46 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: sysmond
Model: MacBookPro13,3, BootROM MBP133.0226.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.38f5
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics530Item, Intel HD Graphics 530, Built-In
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro460Item, AMD Radeon Pro 460, PCIe, 4096 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x15A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.47.1a8)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 11.9
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 11.9
```

Another one:

```
Anonymous UUID:       2553145D-8FD9-2DA2-070C-9095DBCBAEA6

Sun Nov 20 23:43:46 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff8011be629d): "TLB invalidation IPI timeout: " "CPU(s) failed to respond to interrupts, unresponsive CPU bitmap: 0x40, NMIPI acks: orig: 0x0, now: 0x0"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3789.21.4/osfmk/x86_64/pmap.c:2724
Backtrace (CPU 5), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff922766b880 : 0xffffff8011af368c 
0xffffff922766b900 : 0xffffff8011be629d 
0xffffff922766b9a0 : 0xffffff8011bed01e 
0xffffff922766baa0 : 0xffffff8011bedfca 
0xffffff922766bb10 : 0xffffff8011b7b0b8 
0xffffff922766bc50 : 0xffffff8011b7a9bc 
0xffffff922766bc80 : 0xffffff8011b76523 
0xffffff922766bcb0 : 0xffffff8011f8d8ee 
0xffffff922766bd50 : 0xffffff8011f8daee 
0xffffff922766bd90 : 0xffffff8011f90add 
0xffffff922766be20 : 0xffffff8011f90ce1 
0xffffff922766bf50 : 0xffffff8012027cba 
0xffffff922766bfb0 : 0xffffff8011aa5f46 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: sysmond

Mac OS version:
16B2659

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Wed Oct 19 20:31:56 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.4~4/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 75CA1C4D-7BF4-321B-B544-D8F1B6D60EF8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000011800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8011a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011900000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4030459803734
last loaded kext at 3308191198429: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f95da7000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 2516934127079: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f95d9b000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.radiosilenceapp.nke.PrivateEye  1.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.23
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.1f7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.74
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.kext.AMD9500Controller    1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 103
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1110.4.1a8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.23
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.1f7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.23
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.74
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.74
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.15
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.0.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.20.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro13,3, BootROM MBP133.0226.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.38f5
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics530Item, Intel HD Graphics 530, Built-In
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro460Item, AMD Radeon Pro 460, PCIe, 4096 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x15A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.47.1a8)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.1f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 11.9
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 11.9
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First thing that drew my eye was that the panic appears to be 'networking' based.

```
Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily
```

The only non-Apple kext you have is `com.radiosilenceapp.nke.PrivateEye`

[Here is a relevant search](https://www.google.com/search?q=com.radiosilenceapp.nke.PrivateEye) & my detective eyes identified the following as most helpful result:

[Radio Silence>Private Eye: Frequently Asked Questions](https://radiosilenceapp.com/private-eye/faq)  which states

> **What version of Mac OS X do I need?**
> Private Eye runs on Mac OS X Lion (10.7), Mountain Lion (10.8), Mavericks (10.9), Yosemite (10.10),
> and El Capitan (10.11).

Uninstall this “prime suspect” and/or ask the developer about a Sierra-compatible update is my advice.